# exception at memory location (vector issue) opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector

I am trying to find average of 2x2 block pixels within a window of 6x6 of overall image size mxn. I can able to find the average of block till the end of first row and when the code has to move to next row, it throws runtime error "exception at memory location"

```
vector<int>m; vector<int>m1; vector<int>m2; vector<int>m3;vector<int>m4; vector<int>m5; vector<int>m6; vector<int>m7; vector<int>m8;

 for (int i = 2; i < road.rows - 2 ; i++){
    for (int j = 2; j < road.cols - 2 ; j++){           

        //center block          
        int avg=(round((road.at<uchar>(i, j) + road.at<uchar>(i, j + 1) + road.at<uchar>(i + 1, j) + road.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 1)) / 4));
        //top left block            
        int avg1= (round((road.at<uchar>(i - 2, j - 2) + road.at<uchar>(i - 2, j - 1) + road.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 2) + road.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1)) / 4));
        //top           
        int avg2 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i - 2, j) + road.at<uchar>(i - 2, j + 1) + road.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) + road.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 1)) / 4));
        //top right block           
        int avg3 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i - 2, j + 2) + road.at<uchar>(i - 2, j + 3) + road.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 2) + road.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 3)) / 4));
        //left block            
        int avg4 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i, j - 2) + road.at<uchar>(i, j - 1) + road.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 2) + road.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 1)) / 4));
        //right block           
        int avg5 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i, j + 2) + road.at<uchar>(i, j + 3) + road.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 2) + road.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 3)) / 4));
        //bottom left block         
        int avg6 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i + 2, j - 2) + road.at<uchar>(i + 2, j - 1) + road.at<uchar>(i + 3, j - 2) + road.at<uchar>(i + 3, j - 1)) / 4));
        //bottom            
        int avg7 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i + 2, j) + road.at<uchar>(i + 2, j + 1) + road.at<uchar>(i + 3, j) + road.at<uchar>(i + 3, j + 1)) / 4));
        //bottom right block            
        int avg8 = (round((road.at<uchar>(i + 2, j + 2) + road.at<uchar>(i + 2, j + 3) + road.at<uchar>(i + 3, j + 2) + road.at<uchar>(i + 3, j + 3)) / 4));
        m.push_back(avg);
        m1.push_back(avg1); 
        m2.push_back(avg2);
        m3.push_back(avg3);
        m4.push_back(avg4);
        m5.push_back(avg5);
        m6.push_back(avg6);
        m7.push_back(avg7);
        m8.push_back(avg8);         
    }
  }
```

Help me out of this error;

Comment: And *where* do you get the crash? Have you tried to run your program in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and locate where it happens in your code?

Comment: Can't you just use one of the filters to find the info? For example [normalized box filter](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#blur) used by `blur` method.

Comment: how can I use box filter for my purpose of getting average of block